Evaluate: $\int{\frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^3x}dx}$
Evaluate: $$\int{\frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^3x}\ \mathrm dx}$$
My attempt:-
Put $\cos x=t$ so, $-\sin x\ \mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$ ,
Hence,
$I= -{\int{\frac{t^4}{(1-t^2)^2}}dt}$ $=-\int{\frac{t^4-1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt}-\int{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt}$
$=-\int{\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}dt}-\int{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt}$
To solve:
$-\int{\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}dt}$ $=-t+2\int{\frac{1}{1-t^2}dt}$ ${=-t+\ln{\frac{1+t}{1-t}}}$
But its way different, than the real answer which is;
$$-{\frac{\cos^3x}{2\sin^2x}}-{\frac32}\cos x+{\frac34}{\log{\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}}+c$$ and I don't know how to solve $\int{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt}$; please, provide a detailed solution and if possible by some simpler method.

You can try $t=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$ with integrals like this. A quick search for universal trig substitution will give a lot of nice examples.

There are many similar posts for $\int\dfrac1{(t^2-1)^2}dt$ see Approach0. And this post for the original integral.

Concerning $(t^2-1)^{-2}$ I would use ${1\over 4}[(t-1)^{-1}-(t+1)^{-1}]^2.$

You can simplify $\int\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$ as follows:
$$\begin{aligned} 
\int\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}dt &=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t+1-(t-1)}{(t+1)^2(t-1)^2}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(t+1)(t-1)^2}dt-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(t+1)^2(t-1)}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t+1-(t-1)}{(t+1)(t-1)^2}dt-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t+1-(t-1)}{(t+1)^2(t-1)}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}dt-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{(t+1)(t-1)}dt-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{(t+1)(t-1)}dt+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{4(1-t)}-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{t+1-(t-1)}{(t+1)(t-1)}dt - \frac{1}{4(1+t)}\\
&=\frac{t}{2(1-t^2)}-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{t-1}dt+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{t+1}dt\\
&=\frac{t}{2(1-t^2)}-\frac{1}{4}\ln(t-1)+\frac{1}{4}\ln(t+1)\\
&=\frac{t}{2(1-t^2)}+\frac{1}{4}\ln(\frac{t+1}{t-1})
\end{aligned}$$
Please let me know if I made an arithmetic mistake here.

Writing  the numerator as  $$\dfrac{(t+1-(t-1))^2}4$$ should help better

In fact
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}dt\\
&\overset{t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=&-\frac18\int\frac{(1+x)^2}{x^2}dx\\
&=&-\frac18\int(x^{-2}+\frac2x+1)dx\\
&=&-\frac18\bigg(-\frac1x+2\ln|x|+x\bigg)+C\\
&=&\frac18\frac{1+t}{1-t}-\frac14\ln\bigg|\frac{1-t}{1+t}\bigg|-\frac18\frac{1-t}{1+t}+C\\
&=&\frac{t}{2(1-t^2)}-\frac14\ln\bigg|\frac{1-t}{1+t}\bigg|+C.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Can we do that? I might be missing something here, but once we set $t=\cos \theta$ earlier, we have restricted the set of values of $t$. Can we now set $t$ to this arbitrary function? For example, $t$ should be able to take the value -1, but this substitution cannot. Please let me know if there’s a gap in my understanding here. :)

Alternative approach:
$$\int ~\frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^3x} ~dx = \int ~\frac{ [ ~1 - \sin^2x ~]^2}{\sin^3 x} ~dx$$
$$= \int ~\frac{1 - 2\sin^2x + \sin^4 x}{\sin^3 x} ~dx$$
$$= \int ~\left[ ~\csc^3 x - 2\csc x + \sin x ~\right] ~dx. \tag1 $$

Since $\displaystyle \int \sin x ~dx = - \cos x,~$ the entire problem represented in (1) above has been reduced to computing the integrals of $~\csc x,~$ and $~\csc^3 x.$
The problem is then easily completed simply by using the internet as a resource, googling "integral of csc x" or "integral of csc^3 x".  For examples,
CueMath derivation of integral of csc x gives a step by step derivation of $~\displaystyle \int \csc x ~dx.$
Socratic.org derivation of integral of csc^3 x gives a step by step derivation of $~\displaystyle \int \csc^3 x ~dx.$
